# JAVASCRIPT - Get Value from Parent Array of Objects, inside the Child Object after Array Flattening

Tags: javascript, arrays, ramda.js, flatten

I have an Array of Objects, which has some values. Examples:

```
bigArray: [
  {
   greatName: 'Name String - #1',
   array: [{
     id: 1,
     name: 'string name - #1'
   }]
  },
  {
   greatName: 'Name String - #2',
   array: [{
     id: 2,
     name: 'string name - #2'
   }]
  },
  {
   greatName: 'Name String - #3',
   array: [{
     id: 3,
     name: 'string name - #3'
   }]
  }
]
```

I used the following composed functions from ramda, in order to get all Arrays `array` properties value and flatten them into a single array:

```
  const extractRB = compose(
    flatten,
    map(props(['array']))
  );
```

Which gave me back the following array:

```
// Flatten Array:
flatten: [
  {
     id: 1,
     name: 'string name - #1'
   },
   {
     id: 2,
     name: 'string name - #2'
   },
   {
     id: 3,
     name: 'string name - #3'
   }
]
```

Now, that is a requirement, for my feature. **THE PROBLEM is I also need the `greatName`, property value inside each object, in order to map through them. But I cannot find a way to actually get the correct values inside the object..**

What I want to achieve is this Array of Objects. `Keep in mind that I can have dozens of Objects in Big Array, and hundrends of Objects inside each child array`:

```
// Flatten Array:
flatten: [
  {
     id: 1,
     name: 'string name - #1'
     greatName: 'Name String - #1',
   },
   {
     id: 2,
     name: 'string name - #2',
     greatName: 'Name String - #2',
   },
   {
     id: 3,
     name: 'string name - #3',
     greatName: 'Name String - #3',
   }
]
```

I did this, which is spreading the original object from the flatten array and add the `greatName` property to it, but how to calculate which is the correct value for each object. There is no common value between the object and the array to condition on:

```
flatten.map(flatObj =>  {...flatObj, greatName: bigArray.map(// what operation can I do here, to get the correct value for each object inside the `bigArray` )});
```

I tried quite a few conditional operation, but they will always return false. Mayne there is a way to do it with the length of each `array` but not sure how to do it.

**Help would be greatly appreciated..!! Thank you!!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var bigArray= [
    {
     greatName: 'Name String - #1',
     array: [{
       id: 1,
       name: 'string name - #1'
     }]
    },
    {
     greatName: 'Name String - #2',
     array: [{
       id: 2,
       name: 'string name - #2'
     }]
    },
    {
     greatName: 'Name String - #3',
     array: [{
       id: 3,
       name: 'string name - #3'
     }]
    }
  ]


  console.log(bigArray.flatMap(({greatName, array}) => array.flatMap(x => ({greatName, ...x}))))
```

If `array` property always have only 1 element, so you can write it shorter:

```
  bigArray.map(({greatName, array}) => ({greatName, ...array[0]}))
```

Comment: As I said, in the question. Array obviously doesn't have one element.. It has hundred or even thousands of object. Thank you though!!

Comment: Anyway, my first example works for multiple elements

Comment: I have. Thank you!!

Comment: If you want to use your flatten, you can do this: ` flatten.map(flatObj =>  ({...flatObj, greatName: bigArray.find(x => x.array.find(a => a.id === flatObj.id) ).greatName}));`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this once, may be this will solve your problem:

```
bigArray.forEach((item)=>{
item.array.greatName  = item.greatName;
delete item.greatName;
})
```

Just console bigArray and don't use this and just try with above method

```
 const extractRB = compose(
    flatten,
    map(props(['array']))
  );
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Not possible in this occasion. I have another 25 properties in those objects.. And I need kind of a universal solution, since I will re-use that solution, for the `greatName` for other properties in different parts..